# Android: what I've missed since SDK 1.0?

Tags: android, sdk

I've studied several Android books in 2009 and have fiddled with SDK 1.0 with a couple of test projects; then I moved to another side project with different technologies and I have not followed the updates of the SDK in term of cool new features.

Do you mind to give a brief recap of what I've missed since SDK 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this information on http://developer.android.com/

- [New in 1.5](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.5.html)
- [New in 1.6](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.6.html)
- [New in 2.1](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html)
- [New in 2.2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html)